# Conversion Error when opening JMX file from JMeter 2.7 in JMeter 2.11

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to open a jmx file written with Apache JMeter 2.7 in the last release Apache JMeter 2.11.
I am getting this errors log :

```
2014/09/10 09:29:44 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: C:\Temp\MEGA\Test_Anywhere_750 _Part3.jmx 
2014/09/10 09:29:44 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='C:\Temp\MEGA' 
2014/09/10 09:29:44 WARN  - jmeter.config.CSVDataSet: Could not translate shareMode=Toutes les unités using Locale:  
2014/09/10 09:29:44 WARN  - jmeter.config.CSVDataSet: Could not translate shareMode=Toutes les unités using Locale:  
2014/09/10 09:29:46 ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector : kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector
---- Debugging information ----
message             : kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[3]/kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector
line number         : 92330
------------------------------- : kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector : kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector
---- Debugging information ----
message             : kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[3]/kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector
line number         : 92330
-------------------------------
message             : kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector : kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector
---- Debugging information ----
message             : kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[3]/kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector
line number         : 92330
-------------------------------
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector : kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:65)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[3]/kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector
line number         : 92330
version             : 2.11 r1554548
------------------------------- 
2014/09/10 09:29:46 WARN  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Unexpected error org.apache.jmeter.exceptions.IllegalUserActionException: Empty TestPlan - see log file
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:174)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:136)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doAction(Load.java:92)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am using the version 7.0.650.20 of JAVA.
Does anyone have an idea why I could not open my file ?

Regards

Sylvie

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You're using Third Party [jmeter-plugins.org](https://jmeter-plugins.org) plugins.

You need to add the required jar in lib/ext so that it works.

Download plugins-manager.jar from [here](https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/) and put it into lib/ext directory, then restart JMeter.

**Note you need to do it each time you upgrade your jmeter version !**

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) will help you.

Comment: I downloaded the jar from this link: jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager. Then you need to install the UDP Protocol Support plugin.

Comment: Install to lib/ext the jar located here (plugins-manager.jar): https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/

Answer (score 16):

Download [plugins-manager.jar](https://jmeter-plugins.org/get/) and put it into lib/ext directory, then restart JMeter.

Comment: This link no longer works, do you know where this list went?

Comment: Thanks, @Flotok! I've updated content to the actual state. The list is on https://jmeter-plugins.org/

Answer (score 10):

I am using JMeter 3.3 and answers above did **not** work for me.

**SOLUTION:**

1. Download `plugins-manager.jar` from https://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/
2. Put `plugins-manager.jar` into JMeter/lib/ext
3. Restart `JMeter`
4. Open JMX script, it will ask to download dependencies, click `Yes, install it`.
   [image]
5. Dependencies will be downloaded and JMeter will be restarted.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47509713/3915006)

Comment: Solution still work for `v5.6.2`

Answer (score 6):

1)Download standard JMeterPlugins-Standard-1.4.0.zip from http://jmeter-plugins.org/#/

2)Extract it and go inside extracted folder /lib/ext.

4)Copy JMeterPlugins-Standard.jar and CMDRunner.jar from /lib/ext to Jmeter/lib/ext

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work for me. I copied all two jars from lib/ext to jmeter/lib/ext and still am getting the same error. (Apache JMeter 3.3)

Answer (score 3):

For people who are using command line for running JMeter, here is how to install a new plugin.

After placing the plugin manager jar in the /lib/ext/, download the latest cmdrunner from this URL by changing the version.

```
wget http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=kg/apc/cmdrunner/2.2/cmdrunner-2.2.jar
```

Copy the cmdrunner to jmeter/lib/ directory

```
mv cmdrunner-2.2.jar apache-jmeter-5.1.1/lib/
```

Execute the following command to generate script file PluginsManagerCMD

```
java -cp apache-jmeter-5.1.1/lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller
```

After the script is generated, you can use it to install a particular plugin

```
apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin/PluginsManagerCMD.sh status
apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin/PluginsManagerCMD.sh available
apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin/PluginsManagerCMD.sh install jpgc-tst=2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

1. download jar files from https://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/file/JMeterPlugins-Standard-1.4.0.zip
2. extract and copy lib/etx/*.jar to jmeter/lib/etx/

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work for me. I copied all two jars from lib/ext to jmeter/lib/ext and still am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the proxy server configured if you are behind one.

I had [plugins-manager.jar](https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/) in `lib\ext`, but it only worked once I added the proxy to `bin\system.properties`:

```
http.proxyHost=my.proxy.server
https.proxyHost=my.proxy.server
http.proxyPort=8080
https.proxyPort=8080
```

Or:

```
jmeter -H my.proxy.server -P 8000 -u username -a password
```

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server