# I've tried to open a jmx file in jmeter and received this error

Tags: java, jmeter

Error from terminal after running:
$ ./jmeter -n -t Katia_4k1.jmx

```
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'/Users/yahavhoffman/Desktop/Katia_4k1.jmx', missing class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : 
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[8]/com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig
line number         : 347
version             : 3.2 r1790748
-------------------------------
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759977/conversion-error-when-opening-jmx-file-from-jmeter-2-7-in-jmeter-2-11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is regarding missing [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin, you just need to install it and you should be able to open your Test Plan on next JMeter startup (assuming that this is the only missing plugin)

The recommended way of installing JMeter Plugins and keeping them up-to-date is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.google.pl/search?q=blazemeter%20jmeter%20plugins%20manager&oq=blazemeter%20jmeter%20plguins&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.3514j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager WebDriver Sampler]

Comment: how can I identify which plugin is missing so I could install int instead keep bombarding this thread?

Comment: never mind, I've figured it out :)
Thank you for your help :)