# Jmeter throws CannotResolveClassException: com.zeroclue.jmeter.protocol.amqp.AMQPConsumer

Tags: jmeter, amqp

I am trying to import a JMX file and it throws the following exception. I have downloaded jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar and have put in 'lib/ext' folder as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759977/conversion-error-when-opening-jmx-file-from-jmeter-2-7-in-jmeter-2-11).
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the `JMeterAMQP.jar` in your `lib/ext` directory.

To resolve this issue you can check this [JMeter-Rabbit-AMQP](https://github.com/jlavallee/JMeter-Rabbit-AMQP) git project and build an executable `JMeterAMQP.jar` and then just copy the .jar file into your JMeter's `lib/ext` directory. Additionally, you also need [RabbitMQ Java Client](https://www.rabbitmq.com/java-client.html) into your `lib/` directory.

So, here is a quick solution for you:

1. Download `JMeterAMQP.jar` from [this link](https://github.com/jatinaneja/jmeter_amqp/blob/master/JMeterAMQP.jar) and paste it into your JMeter's `lib/ext` directory.
2. Download `amqp-client` from [this link](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/rabbitmq/amqp-client/5.6.0/amqp-client-5.6.0.jar) and paste it in your JMeter's `lib/` directory.
3. Restart your JMeter.

That's it, you should be able to open your JMX file now.